# What is the use of < symbol in mysql?

Tags: mysql

The symbol < was used following query ,But i could not find why it is used and what its purpose

```
c:\>mysql -u root -p < create_database.sql
```

in create_database.sql consist of following

```
CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER 'sonar' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: That's not MySQL.  That's Linux-based systems.  It means to take the stuff on the right and send it to the stuff on the left.

Comment: ok thanks , i have see dis in follwoing video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFlN4bUufi8 ther are using above command in windows machine

Comment: Yes, as Barmar points out in his answer which should be accepted, works in Windows too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Unix shell and Windows `cmd.exe` syntax. It means that the file after `<` should be used as standard input to the command. So it runs the `mysql` command, and the contents of the `create_database.sql` file will be read as input by `mysql`, and it will perform those queries.

Comment: The otehr way around > actually write the output into the destination file.
So when you do mysqldump -u root > backup.sql, it writes all the outputs of mysqldump into the file dump.sql.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` character has nothing to do with mysql. It is part of the command line interface. It does stream redirection.

The `mysql -u root -p < create_database.sql` line takes the contents of the `create_database.sql` file and sets it as the input of the `mysql -u root -p` command. The `mysql` command reads the contents of the file as if it were typed in by the user.